# Jump to end of line, multiple contexts e.g. text editor, browser bar

Tags: text-editor

(tag suggestions for this post welcome)

I used to have a Mac. In various circumstances, if I wanted to jump to the end of a line, I would press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>.

Is there an equivalent on Ubuntu desktop (18.04)?

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> jumps to the end of a word, but not the line. Common use cases: browser URL bar, text document, IDE.

How can I jump to the end of a line in Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the <kbd>End</kbd> key for jumping to the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by entering:`Ctrl + Down Arrow` and to navigate to start of line, it is simply: `Ctrl + Up Arrow`

source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly